# Redis: how to add record in multiple sorted sets

Tags: node.js, redis, sortedset

I am storing user's follower's list as separate sorted sets for each user.

[image]

And for every user I creating separate sorted sets to store their post feeds:

[image]

When user 1 adds new post, I want to add it immediately to all users from **user1-followers** into their respective $userid$-postfeeds sorted sets.

At present, I have used pipeline (using NODEJS) for multiple ZADD commands. Is there any better way to fan-out-write to insert records in multiple sorted sets at same time.

Comment: you could create a Lua script that will do the same logic and will avoid the network traffic, as it just accepts the posting user and does the fanout based on querying the feeds.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, you mean use for-loop in lua script to execute multiple ZADD commands?

Comment: yes, a lua function that given a post and a poster id, will take all its followers from the relevant followers set, and distribute the post to the follower's feed sets. it will do the exact same thing, but instead of (potentially) thousands of  network queries, you will have only one.